# How to make sure TestNG runs methods on test classes in succession instead of interleaved?

Tags: testng

### The situation and the problem

I have several test classes, each with several test methods. All tests use the same test database in the background. Each test class initializes its database contents and then tests stuff in several test methods.

When I run each test individually, they all pass. But when I run several tests at the same time (either using maven or my IDE, IntelliJ), the methods of different test classes are run interleaved, eg. the database initialization of the second class runs after the first class has started but before all test methods of first class have been run so these methods will fail (because the database already contains second class's data).

### Some things I've tried, and some more details

The simplest solution would be to force the TestNG runner to run the classes in succession (ie. wait for all the test methods of a test class to finish before running test methods of another class). Can this be done?

I can probably do this by specifying each class as a separate test in my suite, but I don't want to do this as this means I'd have to add something to the suite whenever I add a test class which is clumsy and error-prone.

Simply asking TestNG to not parallelize anything (eg. setting thread count to 1 or disabling parallel running) doesn't help here since methods still get run in the wrong order (though not simultaneously).

One option would be to use a different database for each test class, but I don't see a simple way to do this (using JPA and Guice).

I'm not currently using DBUnit, Unitils etc.; I don't know these tools very well but I got the impression the don't solve my problems.

I'm using JPA to initialize database in each test class (ie. create entity objects and presist them).

Comment: I think at least part of the problem is that several classes have methods called `testPrepareDb` and other methods annotated `@Test(dependsOnMethods = "testPrepareDb")`. When several such classes are run as part of one test, it seems all dependent methods are run only after *all* `testPrepareDb` methods have been run, which is wrong in my case.
Basically, I'd just want my test classes to translate automatically to separate TestNG tests without having to explicitly state them as `<test>` in the suite xml.

Answer (score 6):

Even in sequential mode TestNG could interleave test methods from the same suite. It does guarantee the sequence @BeforeClass -> @Test -> @AfterClass but it can do something like:

```
before class1
    test class1.method1
before class2
    test class2.method1
    test class1.method2
after class1
    test class2.method2
after class2
```

The solution is to force each class in a different suite (which are executed truly sequentially). As of version 2.16, the maven surefire plugin puts each class in a separate suite so the problem is fixed.

On the other hand, IDEA (even the latest 13 EAP) generates an xml file with all classes in the same suite. Hopefully IDEA will follow suit and fix this too. Interleaved tests are a showstopper when working with shared resources such as databases.

Comment: Thanks for the tip about the new feature in 2.16! I can't seem to get it to work though; is some special configuration necessary? The parallel etc. params in [the docs](http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/test-mojo.html#parallel) don't seem relevant (and seem to be for JUnit anyway).

Comment: No special configuration is needed. I don't use suite XMLs or anything  like that. I just specify the file patterns in the surefire configuration. UPDATE: I've also patched testng to execute classes sequentially and fix the whole thing at the root but it's not yet ready for a pull request.

Comment: This doesn't work for me either, and I'm using surefire 2.17.  I think the issue may be as @mazi described in his comment below his original question - if you have multiple methods with the same name, even on different classses, and you depend on one of them, TestNG treats this as a dependency on all of them.  This is a guess though, as I've already munged all my interdependent methods together to get round this and have run out of time to investigate further.

Answer (score 2):

came here with a similar problem. I think group-by-instances="true" could be a solution.

Answer (score 1):

TestNG offers several parallel strategies. It looks like `methods` is too aggressive for your needs but have you looked at `classes` or maybe `instances`?

Comment: I've tried `false` before; now I tried `methods`, `classes` and `tests` too (`instances` doesn't seem to be a valid option). None help. As I wrote, the problem is not parallelization, it's ordering.

Comment: Tuning multithreading wouldn't help as the strategy you need is "run methods in parallel as long as they belong to the same class". It is not available.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote an article discussing some ways to sequence tests in TestNG:

http://ancient-marinator.blogspot.com/2013/05/on-testing-scheduling-your-tests.html

Naturally, the best source for information is at home: http://testng.org/doc/index.html

Comment: Thanks, this is a good blog post. It is very general though and doesn't address my particular problem.

Comment: The only ordering you need to apply in TestNG is to put a `@Test(groups="test1")` at the start of the first class, `@Test(groups="test2",dependsOnGroups="test1")`, etc, for each class in sequence. This will serialize the running on a class basis.

Comment: @BobDalgleish - but this means you have to put all your tests into groups.  More importantly though, it also means you can't run one class on it's own any more, without the other class also being executed.

Answer (score 0):

Use [method interceptors](http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#methodinterceptors) (=write and enable a custom one) to control the ordering.

Also, each class might use its own database sandbox: wrapping each test class into a transaction might possibly help.

Having individual suffix for tables/db set up for each class would even let your test methods run in parallel (I guess the first two options would not).

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't use dependsOnGroups at the class level because if any test method in any of the classes you're depending upon fails it won't run your class at all... This is the real downside of using 'dependsOn' groups (or methods). I would try first just setting @Test(group = thisClassName) at the class level, then identify the class with a test tag in your testng.xml file. Then control the ordering of your class runs in the xml as a list of these tests. I believe you may need to also set PreserveOrder = "True" on the next higher level tag in the xml. I would avoid using dependsOn except when you really need it for dependancies, but not for controlling order. Hope this helps. -JR

Answer (score 0):

We were running into this same issue, most people say it's caused by using dependsOn, but our solution was just setting priorities at a test level for some of our tests.  I set up a Test Listener to re-prioritize our tests so that they run in the correct order.  This is based on saberduck's solution in 
https://github.com/cbeust/testng/issues/106

This solution will preserve the test priority by concatenating it to the class priority.

```
package testng_Listeners;
import java.lang.reflect.Constructor;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import java.util.HashMap;
import org.testng.IAnnotationTransformer;
import org.testng.Reporter;
import org.testng.annotations.ITestAnnotation;

//Listener to fix TestNG Interleaving issue. I had to re-write this as the original example I had did not allow for priority to be manually set on a test level.
public class RePrioritizingListener implements IAnnotationTransformer {

HashMap<Object, Integer> priorityMap = new HashMap<Object, Integer>();
Integer class_priorityCounter = 10000;
// The length of the final priority assigned to each method.
Integer max_testpriorityLength = 4;

@Override
public void transform(ITestAnnotation annotation, Class testClass, Constructor testConstructor, Method testMethod) {


// class of the test method.
Class<?> declaringClass = testMethod.getDeclaringClass();
// Current priority of the test assigned at the test method.
Integer test_priority = annotation.getPriority();
// Current class priority.
Integer current_ClassPriority = priorityMap.get(declaringClass);

if (current_ClassPriority == null) {
    current_ClassPriority = class_priorityCounter++;
    priorityMap.put(declaringClass, current_ClassPriority);
}

String concatenatedPriority = test_priority.toString();

// Adds 0's to start of this number.
while (concatenatedPriority.length() < max_testpriorityLength) {
    concatenatedPriority = "0" + concatenatedPriority;
}

// Concatenates our class counter to the test level priority (example
// for test with a priority of 1: 1000100001; same test class with a
// priority of 2: 1000100002; next class with a priority of 1. 1000200001)
concatenatedPriority = current_ClassPriority.toString() + concatenatedPriority;

//Sets the new priority to the test method.
annotation.setPriority(Integer.parseInt(concatenatedPriority));

String printText = testMethod.getName() + " Priority = " + concatenatedPriority;
Reporter.log(printText);
System.out.println(printText);

}
}
```

Also you'll need to add the listener to your testng.xml

```
<suite name="Suite" configfailurepolicy="continue" >
<listeners>
<listener class-name="testng_Listeners.RePrioritizingListener"></listener>
</listeners>
```