# Jenkins mixing up tests from different Java classes

Tags: java, testing, jenkins, testng, surefire

We have a project with lots of tests running against a database. Many of the tests set up the database using @BeforeClass, and clean it out using @AfterClass, which works fine when we run the tests locally. When Jenkins runs them, it mixes up the order so tests from different classes are intermixed. For instance, A.TestAlpha, B.TestFoo, A.TestGamma. Then inevitably the tests fail because they don't have the correct setup.
My understanding of Jenkins is that it's supposed to run one class of tests at a time. Is there some config somewhere that might tell it to run the tests in this weird way?

(edit)
The same sort of problems occur running tests locally with `mvn`.
From `mvn help:effective-pom`

```
(project)
    <plugin>
      <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>2.17</version>
      <configuration>
        <includes>
          <include>**/When*.java</include>
          <include>**/Test*.java</include>
          <include>**/*Test.java</include>
          <include>**/*TestCase.java</include>
        </includes>
      </configuration>
    </plugin>
(module)
    <plugin>
      <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>2.17</version>
      <executions>
        <execution>
          <id>default-test</id>
          <phase>test</phase>
          <goals>
            <goal>test</goal>
          </goals>
          <configuration>
            <includes>
              <include>**/When*.java</include>
              <include>**/Test*.java</include>
              <include>**/*Test.java</include>
              <include>**/*TestCase.java</include>
            </includes>
          </configuration>
        </execution>
      </executions>
      <configuration>
        <includes>
          <include>**/When*.java</include>
          <include>**/Test*.java</include>
          <include>**/*Test.java</include>
          <include>**/*TestCase.java</include>
        </includes>
      </configuration>
    </plugin>
```

Comment: JUnit can be run multithreaded. Without more information about _how_ Jenkins is running your tests there's not a lot we can help you with besides says that multithreading is turned on.

Comment: I assume you use Maven. Did you try to run locally with the `mvn clean install` in the console and what is the result?

Comment: Running tests by `mvn clean install` does seem to show the same problems. Does that indicate a surefire problem? We don't have parallel or forking explicitly configured in our surefire configuration

Comment: Could you run `mvn help:effective-pom` and double check your surefire config?

Comment: There doesn't seem to be anything about multithreading in the output of `mvn help:effective-pom`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to everyone who attempted to help.
The bug apparently lies in TestNG.

[How to make sure TestNG runs methods on test classes in succession instead of interleaved?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17272589/how-to-make-sure-testng-runs-methods-on-test-classes-in-succession-instead-of-in)