# TestNG: how to specify test method order from multiple classes?

Tags: java, netbeans, testng

I've read that TestNG will allow you to run methods from different classes in any order you specify.  I've read through this entire tutorial and still have not found out how to do it.
https://www.tutorialspoint.com/testng/

"dependsOnMethods" seems like is what I want but example shows only methods in same class.  How do do something like "dependsOnMethod 10 from class 6"?

You'd think you would be able to specify exact order of execution in testng.xml.

Comment: Re _"You'd think you would be able to specify exact order of execution in testng.xml"_, why do you even want to run test cases from different classes in a specific sequence? Are you asking out of curiosity (which is fine), or do those tests truly need to be run in a specific sequence?

Comment: Database needs to exist before methods can be run against it.  Files must be imported before analysis can be run on them. On and on.  I'm not talking unit tests where each test can stand on its own.  As I've read, people switch to TestNG due to jUnit's many limitations, order being the most important for me.

Comment: OK understood, but doesn't all that setup stuff (database creation, file imports, etc.) properly belong in some _@BeforeXXX_ method such as **@BeforeSuite** (_"[The annotated method will be run before all tests in this suite have run](http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html)"_)? In that scenario you don't care about the order in which actual tests are run. Apologies if I'm misunderstanding, but it doesn't seem that the setup actions you describe belong in any **@Test** method.

Comment: Our application has a couple dozen big classes, each with a couple dozen methods.  Makes sense that some of them could be run using @BeforeSuite.  I guess I need to understand the test suites better and the order in which they run.  Does a test suite allow methods from different classes to be included or do they all have to be from the same class?

Comment: Take a look at this SO question, and its answers: [How to make sure TestNG runs methods on test classes in succession instead of interleaved?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17272589/2985643)

Comment: Ahh.  Ok.  A link in that link provided the answer (I hope) using the methods tag.        <methods>
        <include name="zzzTestMethod"/>
        <include name="bbbTestMethod"/>
        <include name="aaaTestMethod"/>
      </methods>

Comment: OK. I saw that, but doesn't the `<include>` approach only work for methods within the same class, whereas you need to guarantee sequentiality among methods in different classes? Or am I misunderstanding the situation?

Comment: It looks like methods tag is nested in class tag so that should provide full control. suite name="Full Test Suite"> <test name="Sequenced Unit Tests"> <class name="com.example.BasicUnitTestOne"> <methods> <include name="zzzTestMethod"/> <include name="bbbTestMethod"/> <include name="aaaTestMethod"/> </methods> </class> </test> </suite>